# rendering a md file in blowdown with pandoc other than blackfriday?

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I have a plain markdown file in my blogdown website:

```
1. Item 1

- Item a
- Item b

2. Item 2
```

When I served my site, the number of the second item "2. Item 2" was restarted from "1", rather than from "2". PS, I don't want to insert more spaces to the unnumbered lists to achieve this.

I guess this results from the render engine `blackfriday`, which is the default render engine of a plain markdown file in Hugo and blogdown. This is actually the case: When I changed my file from a plain markdown file to a R markdown file, the rending results works as expected. So my question is:

Is it possible to correct this in a plain markdown file, either by changing the rendering engine from blackfriday to pandoc, or by making some modification on how the blackfriday is implemented?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your only choice is to change your filename extension from `.md` to `.Rmd`. There isn't a way to specify the Markdown renderer for plain Markdown files (`.md`).